# Do I have to delete an old question so that I can ask a new question?

Tags: bug, reputation

I have asked 10 questions on Server Fault. Is this the maximum limit? Do I have to delete one of my old questions so that I can ask a new question?

Also, I don't have enough reputation on Meta Stack Exchange to comment on existing questions so there is no option to ask a new question! But then the team will mark this as duplicate question! So how to help myself to get out of this vicious circle?

Also there is afamous phrase: "No question is silly" (Swami Vivekananda). 
Then why do we give negative points for questions. Instead of negative points give fewer points, say 1, on worst question and 100 for best question! This will motivate people to ask questions! I know we want to maintain quality of questions but doing that is stopping people from asking questions!

I know that again I will be getting negative points for this post but wrote what I felt so!

I have asked 10 questions on Server Fault. Is this the maximum limit? Do I have to delete one of my old questions so that I can ask a new question?

Answer (score 14):

> I have asked 10 on server fault, is this the maximum limit ? Do i have to delete my old question so that i can ask new question ?

Your account has been automatically question banned on Server Fault - this is due to your questions not getting a good response from the Server Fault community (you have asked 13 questions, 3 of which are deleted, only two of your question have any upvotes the others are either scored zero or negatively - this is not good).

Deleting one of your questions will only serve to put you deeper into a question ban and will not allow you to ask another.

To get out of the question ban, you should follow the guidance in the help article that was linked in the ban message - the ban is automatic and the following the advice on this post is the only way to get out of it:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

> "No question is silly"

Possibly. But some questions are off-topic. Some questions are of very low quality. Some questions are very badly asked. Some questions don't demonstrate any effort by the asker. These all get downvoted. And rightly so. Server Fault (and the other Stack Exchange sites) do not exist to answer any question - silly or not. They have specific scope and quality requirements and if those are not met, the community downvotes.

Comment: So should I undelete my previous question & follow those instructions on serverfault or work on 0 vote questions to come out of ban ?

Comment: Do both. Unless the deleted question is not something you can improve. In short - improve **everything** you can.

Comment: I tried my best to improve ? now really don't know what to do :(

Comment: Edit them. Add details. Explain what you tried. Explain what didn't work. Make it easier for others to answer. Read the [how-to-ask](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) help article and see if you can make your questions follow as much of the guidelines as possible.

Comment: Please someone can help me to come out of ban by adding comments there i will edit accordingly ?

Comment: Ok will give a try again ! Thanks a lot

Comment: I have modified my questions on server fault but still they are 0 voted or negatively voted ! Now until someone up votes it i can't ask new question ? and what if no one up votes it then i won't be able to ask question  in my life on server fault :(  & what about those marked as off topic those will be never reverted then how it will possible for me to come out of ban :(

Comment: "Now until someone up votes it i can't ask new question ?" - yes, that's pretty much it. Have patience and keep improving your posts - there is always something to improve (grammar, spelling - such as I instead of i, formatting, adding details, focusing the question, responding to comments etc...).

Comment: wow that's great ! i modified my question to make it more understandable & got -1 for that :) i don;t think so I will come out of ban :(

Comment: Well, you've edited a question with several answers - you even accepted one. The edit was probably seen as spurious by the downvoter (as it wasn't really adding anything of substance to the question). Focus on the questions that do not have any answers - and made your edits of substance - so they actually help readers understand and answer them.

Comment: If I comment / give answer to others question will hit help to come out of ban ?

Comment: Commenting will not in itself help, answering *could* help, but it will not be a particularly fast way to do it (which also makes sense given that answering and asking are very different skills).

Comment: bty what is limit for down votes to get banned ie how many max bad questions are allowed ;)

Comment: That is not public information, as giving it out will help people (and spammers) game the system.

Comment: Yes you got the point ! But how we will understand this is last question if gets wrong then we are dead (banned) ............ There should be some warning that this is your last question becareful......    :)

Comment: There is such a warning. Some people ignore it...

Comment: I agree i have done mistake but should get help to come out of it ! cause from my side i have given my best still not able to get hint what exactly should i add information to come out of it :(